# Dúvida na construção de WS REST(Contrato)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, web-service, linq

Senhores, peguei um exemplo no livro do john sharp(microsoft press) para construir um REST e veio uma dúvida simples, mas uma dúvida de boas práticas.

Ele usa o BD Northwind. Ele cria um projeto Class Library e aponta esse projeto para a entidade Products. A pergunta é:

Devo criar para cada entidade do meu WS um novo projeto Class Library ou posso fazer uso do mesmo Projeto de várias entidades?

P.S. No meu meu WS usarei 5 Entidades do BD(PDV,Estabelecimento,Usuario,UsuarioPDV e Localidade(Esse em outro Contexto)).

Uma pergunta: Quando eu tenho um URI nesse formato em minha Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/")]
```

Significa que é um URL sem parâmetros? Ou seja, posso ter um URI assim e um método com parâmetro, assim:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ISuporteContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/")]
        public List<string> getCnpjParceiro(string _cnpj);
    }
```

Comment: Acho que você pode criar uma pasta model e criar um .cs para cada entidade que já fica separado.

Comment: Você cria um Class Library para colocar essas entidades (todas) e seu contexto. Depois referencie a mesma seu projeto final.

Comment: Só para uma questão de boas práticas. Um web service REST, tem praticamente três etapas distintas. As Interfaces, Os Contratos e o SVC em si. Essa pastas pode estar na mesma solution, certo? No meu projeto principal, a pasta Model eu tenho apenas os meus EDMX. As minhas .cs estão na pasta Entities. Vejo isso apenas uma forma de organização. Eu havia criado um outro projeto Class Library para começar a desenvolver o meu WS. Se for seguir sua orientação, devo criar um folder e colocar lá as classes do WS, certo? Outro folder para Interface e o SVC será um outro projeto dentro da sln, ok?

Comment: @pnet, é muita informação, acredito que você deve postar todas essas dúvidas na pergunta principal. Eu faço cada projeto separado e se precisar uso as referencias. Exemplo se faço Web colocar uma class Library para o Entity com as classes repository, se crio um Ws crio outro projeto na mesma solution e se precisar usar o Entity faço referencia. Antes eu estudo o que eu vou fazer e a melhor forma de organização. A regra que eu utilizo e em relação a POO, responsabilidades, acoplamento baixo, camadas de melhoramento etc ...

Comment: Exatamente o que eu estou fazendo, um estudo de tudo antes de começar. Não comecei a desenvolver ainda. Preciso de mais subsídio. Confesso que é muita informação sim. Vou desmembrar para ficar mais coeso(Alta Coesão e Baixo acoplamento, eheh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As classes de Entidades você pode manter em um único projeto Class Library (Exemplo: MeuApp.Dominio). Opcionalmente neste mesmo projeto você pode manter as interfaces (Contratos) dos teus serviços, porém os .SVCs devem estar em outro projeto (Web, Console, etC) para permitir um melhor reaproveitamento das classes de domínio e evitar um acoplamento (dependência/referência) forte entre a exposição web dos serviços e a tua lógica de negócio.